# Angular 13, animate a clicked element while leveraging a single animation block

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-animations, angular13

I am creating a simple, single page site (mostly to learn Angular), and cant seem to figure out how to use a single animation to affect different DOM elements. I could define the animation for each element, but that seems extremely ineffective.

Is there a way to animate the image within the clicked button without defining a separate animation block for each element?

Thank you,
Terry

```
<!-- HTML:   -->  
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore()">
      <img
        [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'"
        src="assets/images/morning.png"
      />
    </button>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore()">
      <img
        [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'"
        src="assets/images/poop.png"
      />
    </button>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore()">
      <img
        [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'"
        src="assets/images/cleanRoom.png"
      />
    </button>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore()">
      <img
        [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'"
        src="assets/images/cleanSinks.png"
      />
    </button>
    <button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore()">
      <img
        [@openClose]="isOpen ? 'open' : 'closed'"
        src="assets/images/evening.png"
      />
    </button>
```

```
// .ts file
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition,
} from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chore-list',
  templateUrl: './chore-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chore-list.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('openClose', [
      state('closed', style({ backgroundColor: '' })),
      state('open', style({ backgroundColor: 'blue' })),
      transition('closed<=>open', [animate('0.3s 0.0s ease-in')]),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class ChoreListComponent implements OnInit {
  isOpen = false;
  constructor() {}
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  finishedChore() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible to use a single animation block

here the issue is you are using single `isOpen` variable and single `finishedChore()` function that affects this variable so when one of the buttons is clicked it will change for all of them so my suggestion would be look like this

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('morning')">
  <img [@openClose]="ismorning" src="assets/images/morning.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('poop')">
  <img [@openClose]="ispoop" src="assets/images/poop.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('cleanRoom')">
  <img [@openClose]="iscleanRoom" src="assets/images/cleanRoom.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('cleanSinks')">
  <img [@openClose]="iscleanSinks" src="assets/images/cleanSinks.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('evening')">
  <img [@openClose]="isevening" src="assets/images/evening.png" />
</button>
```

the .ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  trigger,
  state,
  style,
  animate,
  transition
} from "@angular/animations";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",

  animations: [
    trigger("openClose", [
      state("false", style({ backgroundColor: "" })),
      state("true", style({ backgroundColor: "blue" })),
      transition("false<=>true", [animate("0.3s 0.0s ease-in")])
    ])
  ]
})
export class ChoreListComponent implements OnInit {
  //flower list can be done dynamically 
  isevening = false;
  iscleanSinks = false;
  ismorning = false;
  ispoop = false;
  iscleanRoom = false;
  flowerList = ["morning", "poop", "cleanSinks", "cleanRoom", "evening"];

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  finishedChore(flowerClicked) {
    this.flowerList.forEach((flowername) => {
      let varName = "is" + flowername; // assume this as "is"+'noop'=>isnoop
      console.log(varName);
      if (flowerClicked == flowername) {
        this[varName] = !this[varName];
      } else {
        this[varName] = false;
      }
    });

   
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I had a few errors in the types of the variables.  Could you help me understand the need for flowerList?

Comment: I just used them for the for loop to help me decide which one is clicked as I mentioned on the top this can also be done in another way/dynamically

Comment: @TerryDunlap can u post the error throwing here please and in case did u changed the animation styles 

       state("false", style({ backgroundColor: "" })),
      state("true", style({ backgroundColor: "blue" })),
      transition("false<=>true", [animate("0.3s 0.0s ease-in")])

check this https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-antonelli-mi9qn?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: I am getting a few errors, one is: on flowerClicked: Parameter 'flowerClicked' implicitly has an 'any' type.  The second is off of this[varName]: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ChoreListComponent'

Comment: I changed it to use a switch statement then just coded each case with this.ispoop = !this.ispoop.  I'm trying to find a way to make it more dynamic, so if i change the names or number of chores the code still functions
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('ismorning')">
      <img [@openClose]="ismorning" src="assets/images/morning.png" />
    </button>
switch (flowerClicked) {
      case 'ismorning': {
        this.ismorning = !this.ismorning;
        break;
      }

Comment: Yes it will work but u have to add it to urs switch statements too .if it still throws error share ur code in condsandbox and let’s debug it there

Comment: It is working, thank you for all the help.