# animating an item within a list of items, when clicked in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have been trying to animate a single list item when clicked. The animation trigger does not seem to be accessed in the code for the onclick event.

When searching, I came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70600200/angular-13-animate-a-clicked-element-while-leveraging-a-single-animation-block).

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('morning')">
<img [@openClose]="ismorning" src="assets/images/morning.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('poop')">
<img [@openClose]="ispoop" src="assets/images/poop.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('cleanRoom')">
<img [@openClose]="iscleanRoom" src="assets/images/cleanRoom.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('cleanSinks')">
<img [@openClose]="iscleanSinks" src="assets/images/cleanSinks.png" />
</button>
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore('evening')">
<img [@openClose]="isevening" src="assets/images/evening.png" />
</button>
```

Here, the creation of Boolean variable for each item to animate seems impossible for a large number of items or if you don't know in advance how much of items will there be.

I want to know if there is any other method for this, or if I can have access to animation trigger in code to control from there?

Answer (score 0):

I would pass the event to your onClick function and set the parameters for example as id:

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="finishedChore($event)" id="cleanRoom">
```

Then you can access everything you need for going any further inside of your .ts-file.

```
finishedChore(event) {
   var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
   var id = target.attributes.id;
}
```

Comment: please elaborate a bit more. How can you deal with id in click event? I don't know how to access the trigger in code.
If I have to deal with things on pure html element basis then what is the advantage of angular animations?  
Sorry, I am so confused.

Comment: I do not know, what exactly you are trying to achieve. My idea was to give the event (and with it the srcElement from where it was triggered) to your component.ts. This way you have all the freedom to implement any logic you would like to see. The attribute "id" is just an example on how you can give further information to your logic, so that you can differentiate between various buttons and implement unique behaviours to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am new and my question was very basic. I was actually seaching for animationbuilder, to control things in typescript.